# Run More than One slideshows on One Page

Tags: javascript, slideshow, settimeout, setinterval

I want to run multiple slideshows using javascript but failed to do this using setTimeout or serInterval.

Is it possible to run multiple setTimeout or setInterval for multiple Slideshows

my function to change Slideshow

```
myIndex = {};
timeoutHandles = {};

function Start_Slide_With_ID(id)
{

if( myIndex["index_"+id] == undefined || myIndex["index_"+id] == "" )
{
    myIndex["index_"+id] = 0;
}

myIndex["index_"+id] = myIndex["index_"+id]+1; 

data = Get_User_Element(id);

slider_data = data.slider_data;

slide_time = parseFloat(slider_data.slide_time);

// alert(slide_time)

total_slides = 0;

$("#element_"+id).find(".slide_data").each(function()
{

  total_slides++;

})

if( myIndex["index_"+id] > total_slides )
{
    myIndex["index_"+id] = 1;
}

ShowSlider(id,myIndex["index_"+id]);

slide_time = slide_time*1000;


if( timeoutHandles[id] == undefined || timeoutHandles[id] == "" )
{}
else
{
    clearTimeout(timeoutHandles[id])
}

timeoutHandles[id] =  setTimeout(function(){

    Start_Slide_With_ID(id);

},slide_time);


}
```

Comment: To answer your question, **yes**. Now to more important things, _where's your code?_

Comment: There is a bootstrap plugin called "carousel", if you are allowed to use this then have a  look http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/

Comment: no i do not want any plugin i want this with javascript or jquery